# Tampermonkey Script With Bootstrap Not Working

Tags: bootstrap-4, tampermonkey

I'm using the following in my Tampermonkey script

```
// @require      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js
// @resource     https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
// @require      https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

As you can see, jQuery IS before bootstrap, but I get the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.
```

And the page doesn't render. I've tried putting the scripts in a different order but nothing works.

Any ideas on how to get Bootstrap working in Tampermonkey?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

From the bootstrap page https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/ jQuery must come first, then Popper.js, and then our JavaScript plugins.

Put the Bootstrap css first

```
// @require https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Then Jquery

```
// @require https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js
```

Then popper

```
// @require https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js
```

Then Bootstrap javascript

```
// @require https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Remember you want @require not @resource.